# javascript to remove div tags from HTML in wkwebview objective c

Tags: javascript, html, objective-c, wkwebview

I have HTML string like below

```
 <header><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no'></header><!DOCTYPE html><html><head><style>    * {    word-wrap: break-word;    }    </style>    </head>    <body><div style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: 'Segoe UI', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px;"><div data-tid="messageBodyContainer"><div data-tid="messageBodyContent"><div>Thanks for agreeing n.&nbsp; I'm xyz at The &nbsp;&nbsp;and I'll serve as the moderator for the board.&nbsp; We'll be discussing your interactions with each other :</div><div>1) The class will be open for 2 days April 24 and April 25.&nbsp; Please ask questions each day, and read book.2) The approximate time commitment to the books is 30 minutes each day.</div><div></body></html>
```

or like this

```
<header><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no'></header><!DOCTYPE html><html><head><style>    * {    word-wrap: break-word;    }    </style>    </head>    <body><div><span style="font-size: 16px;"><span style="font-size: 16px; font-family: Arial;">Hello and welcome to XXXXXXX bulletin board session!&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span style="font-family: Arial;">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.</span><span style="font-family: Arial;">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</span><span style="font-family: Arial;">Over the next 3 days...</span></span></div><ul>    <li><span style="font-size: 16px;"><span style="font-family: Arial;">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s&nbsp;</span>    </span></li>    <li><span style="font-size: 16px;"><span style="font-family: Arial;">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.&nbsp;</span>    </span></li>    <li><span style="font-size: 16px;"><span style="font-family: Arial;">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</span>    </span></li>    <li><span style="font-size: 16px;"><span style="font-family: Arial;">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and type setting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s&nbsp;</span>    </span></li>    <li><span style="font-size: 16px;"><span style="font-family: Arial;">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</span>    </span></li>    <li><span style="font-size: 16px; font-family: Arial;">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.</span></li></ul></body></html>
```

Div or span tags which give extra space in wkwebview.I want to minimize that space
I am using below javascript but not able to remove the specific tags but it is not working.

```
   - (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didFinishNavigation:(WKNavigation *)navigation {

    NSString *jsCommand = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                           @"var element = document.getElementById('%@'); element.parentElement.removeChild(element);",
                           @"id2"];


    [webView evaluateJavaScript:jsCommand completionHandler:^(id _Nullable stringresult, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        NSLog(@"result=>%@ error->%@",stringresult,error);
    }];
}
```

Please help

Comment: I didn't notice any elements with id="id2" in either of your html samples, did you happen to leave those off?

Comment: I am not good with the javascript. I am not sure which parameter to pass and where.

Comment: Give an example of what exactly you're trying to remove from the html -- it's not clear from the question